# If $S$ is the set of all numbers of the form $3k + 1$, prove that any number $a$ in the set is prime or product of primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$S = \{1, 4, 7, 10, \ldots \}$

$10$ and $25$ are prime with regard to the elements of $S$ but $16 = 4 \times 4$ and $28 = 7 \times 4$ are not.

I have been stuck on this problem as I am not sure of the approach I need to take.

Comment: A little clarity in the question would have helped

Comment: Any natural number is a prime or multiple of primes... Care to clarify? (Also, 10 and 25 aren't primes, 10=2*5, 25=5*5)

Comment: Well the question states that in a set of all numbers of the form 3k+1, the number is either relatively prime to all the elements of the set prior to it, or it can be expressed as a product of such primes.

Comment: @ormy, 10 and 25 are primes when seen in relation with the elements of the set s

Comment: (i) Probably should  say product of primes. (ii)  Sort of applies to $1$ (empty product). (iii) Use strong induction. Suppose the result is true for  all $k$ with $k\lt n$. Show it is true for $3n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that becomes a lot more interesting if you distinguish between primes and irreducibles. For $p$ to be prime, we require that whenever $p \mid ab$, either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ holds true, maybe both.

But $100 = 4 \times 25 = 10^2$, yet $4 \nmid 10$ and $10 \nmid 25$ either.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1$ is in your set $S$ every number is a multiple of a number in $S$. So if you consider $1$ being a prime, we are done.

If you don't consider $1$ being a prime read this:

Is your definition for $p$ being a prime in $S$ the following?
$$a\in S \Rightarrow  ( a=1 \lor a\nmid p)$$
In that case your assertion is trivial: Take an arbitrary element $a\in S$ with $a\ne 1$. If it is not prime, there is a $p\in S$, $p>1$ with $p\mid a$ by definition of $a$ not being prime. Take the least such $p$ then $p$ is prime in $S$ because the $\mid$ relation is transitive. Note that we didn't use the structure of $S$ for the proof. It works with every subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me how do I prove that if a number is not prime, it is a product of two primes?

Comment: @Sameer.dc.sharma This isn't true. But the smallest factor will be a prime because of the transitivity of the $\mid$ relation.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. If $a > 1$ and $a \in S$, let's say $a = pq$, where $1 < p < a$, and $1 < q < a$, and of course $p, q \in S$. $p$ and/or $q$ might not be "prime" either, in which case we can drill down one level further, and keep drilling down as needed (e.g., factor $280$). But if you can't find $p$ and $q$ such that $pq = a$, that doesn't change the fact that $a \in S$, which therefore means $a$ is "prime."

So for each $1 < a \in S$, it is either "prime" or it can be factored into a product of two or more "primes" in at least one way.

Although not strictly necessary, it might help to reassure yourself that this set is closed under multiplication, which means that whichever numbers from $S$ we multiply together, we will get yet more numbers that are also in $S$. For example, suppose $m = 3j + 1$ and $n = 3k + 1$. Then $mn = (3j + 1)(3k + 1) = 9jk + 3j + 3k + 1$, so if you compute $3jk + j + k$ and reset $k$ to that, then you have restated $mn$ as $3k + 1$.

---

As for this business about "prime" and irreducible": in $\textbf{Z}^+ = \{1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots \}$ there is no need to worry about that distinction, because all primes are irreducible and all irreducibles are primes. If $p \in \textbf{Z}^+$ is irreducible, it is enough to check that it's not divisible by any smaller positive integers.

But the irreducibles in $\textbf{Z}^+$ satisfy the stronger condition that if $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$. For example, $2$ and $5$ are primes in $\textbf{Z}^+$, they both divide $100$, and $100 = 2 \times 50 = 4 \times 25 = 5 \times 20 = 10^2$; verify that for each of those pairs, $2$ divides at least one of the multiplicands, and the same goes for $5$.

Now, as Alonzo already showed, the "primes" of $S$ satisfy the condition for irreducibles but not the condition for primes.

Answer (score 0):

I will first clarify the question being asked. Let $S$ be any subset of the positive integers. Say that $n\in S$ is prime (relative to $S$) if there do not exist $a,b\in S\setminus\{1\}$ with $ab=n$. (As Alonso del Arte points out, maybe it would be better to say irreducible instead of prime; but never mind for now.) The question, presumably, is to show that every element of $S$ can be written as a product of prime (relative to $S$) elements of $S$. This includes a product of one prime (i.e., a prime), and it also includes a product of no primes (i.e., $1$) if $1\in S$.

The proof, as André Nicolas comments, is via strong induction on elements of $S$. (Exercise: show that the validity of regular induction or strong induction in $\Bbb N$ implies the validity of either for any subset of $\Bbb N$.) Base case: it's easy to show that the smallest element of $S$ is either prime (relative to $S$) or $1$. Inductive step: given $n\in S$, suppose that every $m$ in $S$ that is less than $n$ can be written as the product of primes. Then either $n$ is prime, so done; or else, *by the definition of prime relative to $S$*, there exist $a,b\in S$ such that $ab=n$. These $a,b$ must be less than $S$, so by the strong induction hypothesis, both can be written as products of primes; hence their product can be as well.